# Vba Left Function not working

Tags: vba, scripting

I'm trying to delete the last  character of a string because I populate the string with a loop that automatically adds a "," after every new string added, like:

```
Do Until EOF(1)
    ...
    (get string)
    ...
    Ref = Ref + String
    Ref = Ref + ","
Loop
Ref = Left(Ref, Len(Ref) - 1)            (Delete last "," of ref)
```

When trying to run this I get a "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" error on the LEFT function.

I've tried to research this error but the only thing I can find is about tools-references are missing, which they aren't (to my knowledge). 
The threads I find are all for vba for excel which isn't the case here, this is code for a script running in a reflection workspace.

Is there another way of deleting the last char of my string? Or is there something wrong that warrants this error? I can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your `left` function isn't working, that's the correct syntax assuming `Ref` is actually a string. I suspect the fact you haven't provided real code is hiding the reason from us.

Keep in mind that there are *two* sub-clauses in that error message:

> Wrong number of arguments ***OR*** invalid property assignment.

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232695%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) details the possible causes.

In any case, it's easier to just do something like (pseudo-code similar to your own):

```
sep = ""
ref = ""
do until eof(1)
    string = getString()
    ref = ref + sep + string
    sep = ","
loop
```

In other words, create the correct string up front rather than trying to fix it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! This combined with the first poster gave me the solution, I use the first run of the loop to start the string right and your sep trick to make sure I don't add a "," at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing the wrong thing and then trying to undo it, why not prevent the mistake in the first place?

It's a lot easier to spot the first run of a loop than the last:

```
Dim first as Boolean
first = True
Do Until EOF(1)
  ...
  (get string)
  ...
  If first Then
    first = False
  Else
    Ref = Ref + ","
  End If
  Ref = Ref + String
Loop
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but could you give a little more information about your solution please? Because after the first run, wouldn't it always add a "," after the ref ? My endgoal is to have a string like " ('Ref1','Ref2',Ref3',...'RefX') " so I can use this string to add to a query.